# csv.writer removes quotes and adds newline

Tags: csv, python-3.6

I got a csv file with normal strings, integers, floats and a column with bytes in it, which I need to encode. I've managed to encode it, but two things are happening now:

1. it removes all quotes from every string column.
2. it adds an empty line after each row.

snippet of input:

```
"text";"6";"1";"ez??R?+??a)???Cs";156156;1561650;0;0;0;74;1720;2012-02-04:486486;"text";"text";"text";"text";490084;49096;False;"{96EE5602-ABD7-4872-A867-5C8D5B28518F}";1;True
```

my code so far:

```
import csv
import base64

with open('input.csv', 'r') as file, open ('output.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    readCSV = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    writeCSV = csv.writer(f_out,delimiter=';', lineterminator= '\r\n')

    for row in readCSV:

        base64_string = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str.encode(row[3]))
        writeCSV.writerow(row)
```

output:

```
text;6;1;ez??R?+??a)???Cs;156156;1561650;0;0;0;74;1720;2012-02-04:486486;text;text;text;text;490084;49096;False;{96EE5602-ABD7-4872-A867-5C8D5B28518F};1;True

text;6;1;ez??R?+??a)???Cs;156156;1561650;0;0;0;74;1720;2012-02-04:486486;text;text;text;text;490084;49096;False;{96EE5602-ABD7-4872-A867-5C8D5B28518F};1;True

text;6;1;ez??R?+??a)???Cs;156156;1561650;0;0;0;74;1720;2012-02-04:486486;text;text;text;text;490084;49096;False;{96EE5602-ABD7-4872-A867-5C8D5B28518F};1;True

text;6;1;ez??R?+??a)???Cs;156156;1561650;0;0;0;74;1720;2012-02-04:486486;text;text;text;text;490084;49096;False;{96EE5602-ABD7-4872-A867-5C8D5B28518F};1;True

text;6;1;ez??R?+??a)???Cs;156156;1561650;0;0;0;74;1720;2012-02-04:486486;text;text;text;text;490084;49096;False;{96EE5602-ABD7-4872-A867-5C8D5B28518F};1;True

text;6;1;ez??R?+??a)???Cs;156156;1561650;0;0;0;74;1720;2012-02-04:486486;text;text;text;text;490084;49096;False;{96EE5602-ABD7-4872-A867-5C8D5B28518F};1;True

text;6;1;ez??R?+??a)???Cs;156156;1561650;0;0;0;74;1720;2012-02-04:486486;text;text;text;text;490084;49096;False;{96EE5602-ABD7-4872-A867-5C8D5B28518F};1;True
```

So:

How can I get rid of the empty line and how can I make sure the "" quotes from the string columns remain in tact. The encodes bytes column should also become a string.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For the newline-problem, use `('output.csv', 'wb')` instead of `('output.csv', 'w')`

Comment: @DanielF that results in: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Oh, sorry, are you on Python 3.x?

Comment: Yes, i am indeed (3.6.1).

Answer (score 3):

define your writer like this. If you later use writerow (as you do) you don't need to add an extra line break.

```
writeCSV = csv.writer(f_out,delimiter=';',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

more magic [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

you can also try to edit the rows as a string

```
import base64


with open('input.csv', 'r') as f, open ('output.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    content = f.readlines()

    for row in content:
        values = row.split(';')
        values[3] = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str.encode(values[3]))

        f_out.write(values.join(';'))
```

Please note that in this case there shouldn;t be any semicolons in any of your strings. I haven't tested the encoding, but you might also need to handle the quote of your byte values (ie first .strip('"'), and then add them back in)

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, I think your solution works partly:

- There is still an empty line after each row
- Now it adds quotes to ALL columns, rather than keeping the existing quotes and adding quotes to the converted bytes column

Comment: Add the `lineterminator= '\n'` option to remove the extra lines.

Comment: instead of csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERICAL you can also try csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL or add quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERICAL also to the reader. The first will only add quotes when necessary (ie strings with white spaces or semicolons), the latter will convert all non quoted element to floats during the read process

Comment: Unfortunately that also results in an error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2012-02-04:486486'

Comment: ok, it might be easiest to not use the csv reader but read the entire row as string, find the bytes, encode them and write back as string

Comment: Why is it removing the existing quotes (present in the input.csv) in the first place?

Comment: because it doesn't sees them as nessessary. CSV doesn't know file types. It only needs to assure that colums are correctly represented (by adding quotes to strings which contains the delimitor). All other quotes are optional. I added a section to my answer to show how you can modify your rows without using the csv reader/ writer.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

The problem is that, when reading, a `csv.reader` will turn every row it reads into a `list` of strings (if you read the documentation carefully enough, you'll see a reader does not perform automatic data type conversion!

If you don't perform any kind of conversion after reading, then when you write you'll end up with everything on quotes... because everything you write is a string.